Laragon Virtual Host doesn't work for Laravel App
I know this question maybe duplicate, but from any answers and questions that I have looked at, no one of them can solve my problem. I use Laragon for my Laravel App project and i want to open the project by using the virtual host. I think I have changed the version of PHP on my Laragon but I doubt about that. After several months not using the Laragon, when I open the Virtual Host, the browser said

whaI have tried many methods, such as:

Reinstall laragon, add new php version, etc
Checking the Read-only setting of hosts file in Windows/System32/driver/etc/...
Turn off the firewall
Check the httpd.conf, but all is clear
Check the auto.test.test.conf, and all is clear
And many checking file, but no one solved my problem.
Any suggestion and solution for this problem please? Thank you


Tunnel connection? There seems to be more going on, than mentioned.

you must put your project in [www] folder and open laragon right click go to www you will find your projects click on it to open

after installing laragon click to open virtual host

I have put all the files in the www folder
